# Phonegap Blackberry App Stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I have successfully signed, built and deployed my blackberry app (using phonegap/cordova 2.7.0) to a device. The problem, however, is that it gets stuck on the splash screen. There are no apparent errors from the device logs. I am only targeting OS 7 and below at the moment.

Also, I should mention that I changed the default 'start screen' from index.html to another index page on my server.

Does anybody have an idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Why did my question get down voted?

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?
Which OS are you targetting (BlackBerry OS, PlayBook OS, BlackBerry 10) ?

Comment: Apologies for posting an incomplete question. I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: More specifically, the start page is a meteor app running on a server. I also tried doing a window.location = 'mySite...' to redirect from the start page, but to no avail...

Comment: BB7 has remote WebInspector. If you package with "-d" and deploy the app you should get a prompt specifying an IP and port to access it. If you refresh from within it, you should be able to debug the startup and see if its a JS issue.

Comment: That is going to help me stacks, thanks a lot Jeff! I'm going to try that now and will report back.

Comment: @jeffheifetz I was unable to successfully attach the WebInspector, I tried bbwp C:\Source\BlackBerry\build\TestApp.zip -g *my Password* -o C:\Source\BlackBerry\Signed -d Is that correct? Also now I get an error on the device "Unknown host domain.com :80" where domain is where the site is hosted.

Comment: The command is correct (the -d being the key part). Do you get an alert when the app launches saying the web inspector IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the app using a remote source, say from your WAMP/XAMP/MAMP server you need to make sure you've whitelisted that domain in your config.xml like so:

```
<!-- point to your source code -->
<content src="http://192.168.0.100/index.html"></content>

<!-- whitelist remote ip, and api's needed -->
<access uri="http://192.168.0.100" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.card"/>
</access>
```

Comment: Thanks chad, I forgot to mention that I have already whitelisted my server, jQuery CDN. I also included the features that I need access to.